# How to pass request parameters to dopost() method in a Servlet on a model.save() in Backbone.js

Tags: servlets, backbone.js

I am trying to integrate my Backbone front end to a Servlet back end. I used both emulateHTTP and emulateJSON to hit my doPost method in the Servlet. I was able to get the JSON response for fetch(from doGet in Servlet).

Now I want to save the model to my back end. I am stuck up about how to pass the request parameters or the model attributes to the post method. Am i missing out any thing here?
Any ideas please...?

Comment: Backbone automatically does a `POST` to a model’s `url` with its parameters when you call `model.save()`. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: Yes, on model.save(), I can use a bean to input the model to my post method for a REST-WS back end. Since a Servlet doPost() method accepts the HTTPServletRequest how do I pass the model's data to the servlet doPost() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone's model.save() invokes the Backbone.sync object, which ultimately calls the jQuery.ajax. All Backbone.sync does is set up the input parameters for the $.ajax, which includes request parameters. So conceivably, if you set up your posting bean as a callable URL, then the $.ajax will handle all the parameters including your model attributes, which will be passed during the save.

Comment: thanks for the Answer. I was able to get the model at the Servlet doPost() as a request parameter "model", even the parameters to be passed are put into "model" request parameter.